# Displaying stdout on screen and a file simultaneously

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, stdout

I'd like to log standard output form a script of mine to a file, but also have it display to me on screen for realtime monitoring. The script outputs something about 10 times every second.

I tried to redirect stdout to a file and then tail -f that file from another terminal, but for some reason tail is updating the screen significantly slower than the script is writing to the file.

What's causing this lag? Is there an alternate method of getting one standard output stream both on my terminal and into a file for later examination?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't say why `tail` lags, but you can use `tee`:

`Redirect output to multiple files, copies standard input to standard output and also to any files given as arguments. This is useful when you want not only to send some data down a pipe, but also to save a copy.`

Example: `<command> | tee <outputFile>`

Comment: Cool command, I wasn't aware of it before. But on my Mac osx box it seems to lag even worse than tail -f. Very odd....

Answer (score 3):

Use tee command:

```
tail -f /path/logFile | tee outfile
```

Answer (score 3):

How much of a *lag* do you see? A few hundred characters? A few seconds? Minutes? Hours?

What you are seeing is buffering. Almost all file reads and writes are buffered. This includes input and output and there is also some buffering taking place within pipes. It's just more efficient to pass a packet of data around rather than a byte at a time. I believe data on HFS+ file systems are stored in UTF-16 while Mac OS X normally use UTF-8 as a default. (NTFS also stores data using UTF-16 while Windows uses code pages for character data by default).

So, if you run `tail -f` from another terminal, you may be seeing buffering from `tail`, but when you use a pipe and then `tee`, you may have a buffer in the pipe, and in the `tee` command which maybe why you see the lag.

By the way, how do you know there's a *lag*? How do you know how quickly your program is writing to the disk? Do you print out something in your program to help track the writes to the file?

In that case, you might not be lagging as much as you think. File writes are also buffered. So, it is very possible that the lag isn't from the `tail -f`, but from your script *writing* to the file.